# No inicia sevidor MySql en Centos

Tags: mysql, centos

Tengo el siguiente los siguientes errores cuando intento iniciar el servicio de MySql en un servidor de CentOS:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start no such file or directory
```

Y cando intento conectar al MySql me saca el siguiente error

```
error 2002 (hy000) can't connect to local mysql server through socket 'var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Has configurado el??? /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf El servicio mysql te inicia??? service mysql start Se necesita más info de tu error compañero

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir más información? Versión de CentOS, de MySQL, como has instalado MySQL y desde cuando te da ese error...¿Existe el fichero? ¿Se cerró correctamente MySQL la última vez que se ejecutó?